# Why do I sometimes see blue faces?

Tags: windows-7, vlc-media-player

There are a bunch of forum posts about this issue from the last several years but no resolution that I could find. I have the newest VLC installed on Windows 7 with the newest nvidia drivers. Suddenly, VLC plays **some** videos in such a way as faces are blue. When viewed in another media player, or when looking at the thumbnails, this is not an issue. Other videos are not affected.

I've tried resetting VLC options, deleting the VLC folder in the AppData area, etc. I have no other color issues. Does anyone have a fix?

Comment: When it happens, is it *just* faces (ie, building look normal) or does everything in the video look that way? When it happens, is it *just* the video (eg the desktop and other windows look normal) or does *everything* look that way?

Comment: @Synetech: R and B swap around, this is a problem between hardware acceleration and a codec.

Comment: @TomWijsman, and it affects *only* faces but not other things in the frame? That's a very strange acceleration-codec problem. (It sounds more like a frayed video-cord; I remember when my monitor's cord had a problem and everything looked purple-blue because the green wire had a bad connection.)

Comment: @Synetech: No, everything. It's most recognizable in faces because they contain a lot of red.

Comment: Ah, well I have not seen that. Any particular codec?

Comment: @Synetech: Had that on my Gentoo, here's an example: http://www.nvnews.net/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=177380 See the attached thumnail.

Comment: That's not a bug, that was just a capture from the *Smurfs* movie. `:-D`

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in the video drivers. Just go to VLC settings and change the video output type until it works.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the video drivers, they just show what you give to them. If you give it wrong, however...

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue...

A bug causes the effect on graphic card drivers, video files for all players, and even Flash players.

For the browsers, if you are seeing this issue in Flash, just right-click on the Flash player and disable hardware acceleration.  If you are seeing the issue in VLC, just go through the video preferences and colors tab to change the color.

Otherwise it is a bug effecting all video players.

If you have the best display drivers, reboot into safe mode, uninstall the display driver, after which you will need to install a new display driver and restart.

Check out [this similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20319/videos-have-blue-faces-when-i-play-them) over at askubuntu.